# Use regex to find multiline blocks

Tags: regex

I am trying to use a regular expression in Notepad++'s search box, to find blocks of lines. The first line in the block contains the word `Entering`, and the last line contains the word `Exiting`:

```
DEBUG [08052018 03:15:35.769] [http-nio-21380-exec-3] [com.citi.risk.common.util.LoggingAspect] Entering method getDataAsOfDates of class com.citi.risk.fdb.dao.DashBoardDAOImpl
DEBUG [08052018 03:15:35.769] [http-nio-21380-exec-3] [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] Executing SQL query [select to_char(max(fac_updated_on),'mm/dd/yyyy') AS MAX_DATE from tb_fd_facilities where fac_updated_by = 'RISKODS_FRMS_FACILITY_JOB']
DEBUG [08052018 03:15:35.833] [http-nio-21380-exec-3] [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] Executing SQL query [select to_char(max(rel_updated_on),'mm/dd/yyyy') AS MAX_DATE from tb_relationships where rel_updated_by = 'SYSTEM']
DEBUG [08052018 03:15:35.903] [http-nio-21380-exec-3] [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] Executing SQL query [select to_char(max(fdn_nav_date),'mm/dd/yyyy') AS MAX_DATE from tb_fund_details_nav where (fdn_updated_by = 'CE_PROCESS' or fdn_updated_by = 'PROC_UPLD_MKT_DATA') and fdn_nav is not null]
DEBUG [08052018 03:15:36.535] [http-nio-21380-exec-3] [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] Executing SQL query [select to_char(max(month_end_date),'mm/dd/yyyy') AS MAX_DATE from tb_optima_feed]
DEBUG [08052018 03:15:36.594] [http-nio-21380-exec-3] [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] Executing SQL query [select to_char(max(archive_date),'mm/dd/yyyy') AS MAX_DATE from pstarchive_dates]
DEBUG [08052018 03:15:36.653] [http-nio-21380-exec-3] [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] Executing SQL query [select  TO_CHAR(max(fdn_pse_date),'mm/dd/yyyy') as MAX_DATE from TB_FUND_DETAILS_NAV where FDN_UPDATED_BY ='CE_PROCESS']
DEBUG [08052018 03:15:37.374] [http-nio-21380-exec-3] [com.citi.risk.common.util.LoggingAspect] Exiting method getDataAsOfDates of class com.citi.risk.fdb.dao.DashBoardDAOImpl
```

What regex can I use to do this?

Comment: What language or tool and what have you tried?

Comment: I am using notepad++ and using regex in it to find the pattern

Comment: You still haven't answered: which regexes have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work:

```
(^|\n).*?Entering.*?Exiting.*?(\n|$)
```

---

Let's break it down. You want to match from the beginning of the string (`^`) or a newline (`\n`):

```
(^|\n)
```

any character in the line (`.`), any number of times (`*`), but get the smallest match possible (`?`) so we don't match over to the next block; followed by the word `Entering`:

```
.*?Entering
```

Then again, any character any number of times, but the smallest match possible, followed by `Exiting`:

```
.*?Exiting
```

Then again, any character any number of times, followed by either (`|`) a newline (`\n`), or the end of the string (`$`).